# How can I convert ArrayList/Set to JSON and post data using postforobject method?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, arraylist, resttemplate

I have set which contains string `["a" , "b" , "c"]` , I want to `POST` json data like (comma seperated and one string) 
Here is

`JSON`

```
{"view" : "a,b,c",
"fruits" : "apple"}
```

to the endpoing using Resttemplate postForObject method? I have used `GSON` but that is not working in my project. Are there any other alternatives?

Here is my code

```
    private run(set<data> datas) {
            Set<string> stack = new hashset<>();
            iterator<data> itr = datas.iterator();
            while (itr.hasnext()) {
                data macro = itr.next();

                if (//some condition) {
                    stack.add(macro);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Resttemplate.getmessageconverters().add(stringconvertor);
            String result = resttemplate.postforobject(endpoint, request, String.class);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is no error, I have difficulty converting above Set in JSON data and passing it

Comment: One way you could achieve this is by creating a POJO, Spring-Boot then automatically converts it to JSON format when the object of this POJO class is passed as the response to a request.

Comment: So, you want to convert set `["a" , "b" , "c"]` to json `{"view" : "a,b,c"}` and pass it in request?

Comment: In your code, what are you trying to output as a JSON Object? It is not very clear.

Comment: Also, do you want to concatenate your set to a string as mentioned in your example? "a,b,c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in a specific class like format, you could go with the POJO approach that is encouraged by Spring Boot. But looking at your example, it seems like you want to achieve a one time JSON Object response.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;    

public static void run(set<data> datas, string endpoint){    
  // build your 'stack' set
  String joined = String.join(",", stack);
  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();    
  obj.put("view",joined);    
  obj.put("fruits","apple");    
  //return the jsonObject as the response to your entrypoint using your method     
}
```

You could also try the following if you use @ResponseBody annotation in Spring Boot that will convert the Response Body to the appropriate (JSON) format.

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("view", joined);
    map.put("fruits", "apple");
    return map;
```

Comment: HttpEntity <String> request = new HttpEntity<>(obj, headers);
It is giving below error at above line -
`error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for HttpEntity<>
            HttpEntity <String> request = new HttpEntity<>(obj, headers);
                                                        ^
    reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: String
      lower bounds: JSONObject
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class HttpEntity` Any suggestions?

Comment: `HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(obj.toString(), headers);
String personResultAsJsonStr = 
      restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);`